# Adding Titles to html table dropdown and text box from a Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function

The last part of my career was all back end ETL and programming. Now I am trying to create a web app (very slowly) in Javascript. I use WebStorm.

The following code works (no style yet), but I just want to add titles above the dropdown and text box. Many web searches have not yielded a solution. How do I add titles in this instance? Thanks!

```js
function addRow(btn) {
    var parentRow = btn.parentNode.parentNode;
    var table = parentRow.parentNode;
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    // cell1 creation: element 1

    var dropdown1 = row.insertCell(0);
    //var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    // CREATE DROPDOWN of Status Choices
    var element1 = document.createElement("select");

    element1.type = "select";
    var one = document.createElement("option");
    one.innerHTML = "One";
    one.value = "1";
    element1.add(one, null);
    var two = document.createElement("option");
    two.innerHTML = "Two";
    two.value = "2";
    element1.add(two, null);
    var three = document.createElement("option");
    three.innerHTML = "Three";
    three.value = "3";
    element1.add(three, null);
    var four = document.createElement("option");
    four.innerHTML = "Four";
    four.value = "4";
    element1.add(four, null);
    // Add options to dropdown list
     dropdown1.appendChild(element1);
     // Text Box
    var textbox1 = row.insertCell(1);
    textbox1.title="Description";
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.size = 50;
    element2.type = "text";
    // Append element2 to the right of element1
    textbox1.appendChild(element2);
}
```

```html
<!--Table with addRow button-->
<table>
  <caption>This is the Table Caption</caption>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button id="addRow" type="button" onClick="addRow(this)">Add</button>
      <label for="addRow">Add a Row</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried many of the dot commands as well.